# .Net 6 How to use more than 1 SearchBase in LDAP Authentication for library "Visus-LDAP UniStuttgart-VISUS/Visus.LdapAuthentication"

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection("LdapConfiguration").Bind(opt);
builder.Services.AddLdapAuthenticationService(opt);
builder.Services.AddLdapSearchService<LdapUser>(opt);
```

I can inject in this way services.

SearchBase is `"SearchBase": "OU=01-EEEEEEE,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=EEEEEEE,DC=com",` but i want to authorize Users also from `"SearchBase": "OU=02-FFFFFFF,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=FFFFFFF,DC=com",`.

I was trying to use that with LDAP syntax to use multiple locations but it does not work.
I was trying option with not providing anything (idea was to use root location to search) but it also failed.